# jQuery - match element that has a class that starts with a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a few links that look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="somelink rotate-90"> ... </a>
```

How can I bind a function to all elements that have a class that starts with "`rotate-`" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector like this:

```
$('a[class^="rotate-"]')
```

---

> Description: Selects elements that
>   have the specified attribute with a
>   value beginning exactly with a given
>   string.

So your code should be:

```
$('a[class^="rotate-"]').click(function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

---

**Note:** If you want to find out elements that contain certain text anywhere in their attributes, you should do this instead:

```
$('a[class*="rotate-"]').click(function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: *all elements* not just `a` (though that does give a specific example, obviously).

Comment: @David Thomas: That is quoted from jQuery docs. Focus on the example I have provided :)

Comment: The starts-with `^` selector will break with precisely the kind of sample the OP posted.

Comment: tx. it works with *, but not with ^. I think it's because I have multiple classes on the link, and the one I'm targeting is not the first

Comment: @Roatin Marth: I saw that and for that reason I  have posted the solution for that too which can be seen at the bottom :)

Comment: The contains `*` selector will have false positives with anything like `foorotate-`, `barrotate-`. This may be ok for the OP however?

Comment: yes, in my case there shouldn't be any classes with similar names :) the link is actually a thumbnail image I'm trying to rotate on mouse over

Comment: @Alex: That is because the text `rotate-` does not come at the start as you have shown in the example of your question. If `rotate-` is to be found anywhere in the attribute, you should use `*` instead. Use `^` when text appears at the start of the attribute.

Comment: Well, `a[class*="rotate-"]` will also match `class="anotherrotate-90"`. *If* that's a problem I believe this will be the solution: `a[class^=" rotate-"], a[class*=" rotate-"]`, i.e. unioning the sets containing the class `rotate-*` first or anywhere else.

Comment: @jensgram: Totally agreed, let's see what OP is up to :)

Comment: @jensgram: good idea. However that also fails to find links that have `"rotate-xxx"` as the first class. I think you meant `a[class^="rotate-"]` in the first selector (note no space).