# jQuery selector for element with mulitple classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<a class="someclass-random1 selected">The third div element.</a>
<p class="selected someclass-random2">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Selector:  `$('*[class^=someclass]')`

This selector works on `<a>`, but not on `<p>`.
Why would that be?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pxon9mzu/4/)

Edit: corrected typo

Comment: Because the `p` classes dont' start with "someclass"

Comment: Also, You can simply do this :) `$('[class^=someclass]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$.expr[':'].startingClass = function(obj){
  return ((/\bsomeclass/).test(obj.className));
};

$('*:startingClass').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxon9mzu/5/)

For more detail: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579108/jquery-has-class-that-starts-with)

---

Or, simply you can use like this:

```
$('[class*=someclass]')
```

The `*` would search anywhere instead of starting from first.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `^=` equates to "starts with" so

```
$('*[class^=someclass]')
```

is looking for any element with a classname that starts with `someclass`

Hence `a` matches and `p` does not

Comment: it was a typo. problem was different.