# jQuery - Using the same script for multiple pairs of items

Tags: jquery

Sure this must've been asked here before but can't find anything.

I have a page with a list of buttons on the left, and a list of divs on the right. Each button has a class that corresponds to the ID of the div. So for example, button one is ".button1" and when clicked, does something to "#div1", ".button2" to "#div2" and so on. If this was my script:

```
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $("#div1").css("color","red");
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
    $("#div2").css("color","red");
});
and so on...
```

...instead of repeating it for every pair, I know I could get the class of the clicked button, check the number on the end, check the div ID's and match it with the corresponding one.

But I don't know how to go about it!

Comment: Is it possible to have couple classes associated with the same button?

Comment: And how is your html structured?

Comment: @DavidThomas It could be structured any way really, I was interested to see different takes on this before I decided on the structure for definite.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko yes, it could have coupled classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this?

Working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AWvv5/2/

Assign click handler to the whole btn class and then, simply replace "btn" with "div" inside the handler.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>

<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e){
    var divId = this.id.replace("btn","div");
    $("#"+divId).css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: Why adding one event handler to each button? This is a school book example of when event delegation is suited for the job.

Comment: @JohanBouveng only when the structure is suitable for event bubbling. We haven't seen any HTML from the OP.

Comment: Great, this is working fine for my current html structure so I'll accept this as the answer!

Comment: @mabi When would the structure not be suitable for event bubbling?

Comment: @JohanBouveng When you have no container for the buttons. Attaching your handler to the body scares the legacy maintainer in me (though I really like it's simplicity).

Comment: @mabi Of course, but these elements should live in a list, fieldset or something. They must be grouped by something.

Answer (score 1):

Ew, here is a minimal working example using event delegation. This works as a charm even if there is 999 buttons. People should stop abusing by adding 999 event handlers when its not needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/5YYDU/

```
$("#buttons").on("click",":button",function(e){
    $("#div"+$(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')).css("background","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [jQuery - match element that has a class that starts with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165183/jquery-match-element-that-has-a-class-that-starts-with-a-certain-string) I'd use

```
$("button[class*='id_prefix']").click(function(){
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  var selector = $.grep(classes, function(el)
    { return el.startsWith('id_prefix'); }
  )[0];
  $('#' + selector).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more flexibility, you can set a target for each button, rather than relying on matching names, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AKkG8/

```
<button class="btn" data-target="#div1">1</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="#div2">2</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="#div4">3, sets 4</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="#div3">4, sets 3</button>

<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

js

```
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

css

```
div {
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
button {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.clicked { background-color: #808080; }
```